# How to get alternative text on image hover

Tags: media

How to display image's alternative text when an user `hovers` on that image.

I have come across few posts that displays `popups` and `views`, but not the `alternative text` of the corresponding images. Some of the modules like [qTip](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) and [Beautytips](https://www.drupal.org/project/beautytips) looks relevant but I suppose those modules doesn't deliver my requirements. If I'm wrong, please let me know how to use those modules to get the `alternative text` displayed on `hover`.

Are there any suggestions regarding how to get alternative text on image hover (possibly without views)

Here, I've created a basic page and in the body I've added an image using advanced text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be different ways to address this issue, but based on my problem statement and requirements I found this solution is quite easy.

I'm injecting `jQuery` code and modifying the `CSS` to get the `hover` effect. My idea is firstly to insert `hover text` as a span through jQuery injection. Secondly, modify the `CSS` in such a way that the text span appears only on hover.

Refer [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Giri99/xk3jkgvz/) for the example code.

I've used [JSInjector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module for injecting jQuery code and modified `reset.css` file

Answer (score 1):

In the field settings for the image, make sure to 'Enable Title field' - this will present a text input for each content under the upload button.  You can include the title here, and it will show on mouse over.

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm not using content type to upload the image. I'm adding an image using advanced text editor options.

Comment: Well, @GIRI, then you have to find a way to implement the title attribute there. I'm not sure, but I'ld guess that [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) has that possibilty implemented.

Comment: Last but not least you could write a little bit jQuery to automatically have the alt attribute set as title attribute @GIRI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734806/is-there-a-way-to-show-alt-text-as-a-mouseover-tooltip-in-firefox-like-ie-does

Comment: yup, sounds great.. I did that

Comment: @GIRI - Would be nice to have your solution as a proper answer to your question. How you wrote and implemented what JS code exactly?

Comment: Yup, good idea. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is in conflict with accessibility best practices. My understanding is that the alt attribute is only meant to be used for contexts where the image does not appear, and is not meant to be used as a compliment to the display of the image itself (as a tooltip or a description). In other words, I think the display of the alt text and the image are intended to be mutually exclusive.

Of course that does not mean that it's technically not possible to use the alt text as a tooltip (some ideas around that are discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734806/is-there-a-way-to-show-alt-text-as-a-mouseover-tooltip-in-firefox-like-ie-does)), it's just discouraged.

Perhaps it would be best to refactor your content so that your hover text (that's intended to be used as a tooltip) is moved to the title attribute. This way you will be in-step with accessibility best practices and will automatically get native tooltip support from browsers.

I suppose that does not *directly* address your question, but it seems like the right note to start with.